# Know where the thread is blocked

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have some python threads that end up eternally blocked waiting for something and I would like python to tell me which statement blocked them.

My case is the following: I am using some libraries that are causing my threads to block. I don't know the code of the libraries, so a first step in debugging is for python to tell me which statements are the guilty ones.

Is there a way for python to "tell me which threads are blocked now and which statement they are in"?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of libraries is usually seen as off-topic, since it can spawn opinion-driven answers. However, if you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, we may be able to help you

Comment: @C.Nivs That is not the main question, so I will just remove it to avoid problems then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this short example program that makes use of [`faulthandler.dump_traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html#faulthandler.dump_traceback) with `all_threads=True` (the default)

It creates 6 threads.  3 will run for a long time, getting "blocked" in the `f1` function.  The other three will run `f2`, which finishes after some short time and exits.

```py
import faulthandler
import threading
import time


def f1():
    time.sleep(99999)

def f2():
    i = 1
    for j in range(10000):
        i += 1


for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=f1).start()

for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=f2).start()


time.sleep(1)

faulthandler.dump_traceback()
```

Upon running this program, you will notice it gets stuck (due to the open threads), but not before giving an output like so:

```
Thread 0x000040f8 (most recent call first):
  File "stack.py", line 7 in f1
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000034d8 (most recent call first):
  File "stack.py", line 7 in f1
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003a60 (most recent call first):
  File "stack.py", line 7 in f1
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00004bb8 (most recent call first):
  File "stack.py", line 24 in <module>
```

As we can see, the main thread is at line 24, (the location of the `faulthandler.dump_traceback` call which triggered this message), and 3 other threads are currently in `f1`, at line 7, `time.sleep(99999)` to be precise.

We don't necessarily know that they are "blocked", beyond the fact that we waited a reasonable amount of time before checking, 1 second in this case.  If necessary, you could perhaps check repeatedly with a loop to monitor which threads remain in the same function after a while.